# Child div 1 pixel away from being flush with left of parent

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div with a child div inside it (the child div acts as a pop up menu).  When the child div pops out it has a tiny space so that it's not lined up with the left of the parent div.

here's the styles:

```
.ButtonContent
{
    display:none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width:275px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
}
.Button
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px; 
    width:276px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="Button" id="Button1" >
    Add <br />
    <div class="ButtonContent" id="ButtonContent1">
         Date purchased:
         <div class="Date" id="datePurchased1"></div><br/>
         Purchase Location:<br />
         <input type="text" maxlength="150" /><br />
         <a>Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two things: the 1px border from the outside `<div>` and the fact that you chose to put one `<div>` inside the other.

The 1px border is positioned outside the leftmost mark of `left: 0px;`. If you remove the border, it works.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MmwYv/

You want .ButtonContent, which is the inner `<div>`, to be displayed outside .Button, which is the outer `<div>`. That is going to cause problems, because the inner one is going to be restricted by the measurements of the outer one. If you take .ButtonContent outside, it works too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NxCp4/

Comment: This was it!  I think the javascript samples I had had that to utilize the fact that it was a child of the other to work.  However, I had never been able to get that functionality to work right and already made work arounds for it, so this made everything work right.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an absolutely positioned element *inside* a relatively positioned one *with a border*, `left:0` positions it within the border which makes it look off by a pixel.

Quick fix: make them both the same width and use `left:-1px;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/RtGfc/

It looks to me like you don't need all this CSS to achieve the look you want, maybe a better fix (without touching your HTML):

```
.ButtonContent
{
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;
}
.Button
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius:4px; 
    width:275px;
    text-align:center;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RtGfc/1/

Comment: This mostly worked except that I had to have the relative positioning on the first one with the absolute on the second one so that the div could pop up without disturbing the page flow.  I added the positioning back in the content's left side was centered so I had to add the float and left positioning back in. After that I had to adjust the width and border of content for it to line up.  The background tip was on the money though.